# When i make connection on phpmyadmin he change my url port

Tags: phpmyadmin

So,

I connect to my phpmyadmin to this url : www.mysite.com/phpmyadmin/

Here all are ok, but when I make a connection he move me on :
www.mysite.com:80 and my website use 443 port so how to fix that ?

Comment: Do you think that with the details you included we can help you?

Comment: Oh, sorry ! I want change the listen port of phpmyadmin